# Why is my Linear-Gradient Converted to Solid Background-Color?

Tags: css, background-image, background-color, web-hosting

I have a simple navbar that I am applying a gradient to, following the example on w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

```
.nav-bar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--primary-bg-color), var(--accent-txt-color));
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This displays correctly when I preview the file in my browser, but I have the page published on Hostinger, and when I visit the live page on Chrome, the gradient is replaced by a solid color. The gradient works fine in other browsers (I tested using Safari and Edge).

When I inspect the page using the Chrome developer tools, it shows that the style applied is this:

```
    background-color: var(--accent-txt-color);
```

I can manually change the style to reflect my published code, which works, but I am confused about why the style is being overwritten in the browser. I do not style the nav-bar anywhere else in my CSS.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that **Chrome was caching parts of my website**, so the updates I was making to this specific feature were not being loaded when I refreshed my site. Once I **cleared my browsing data**, everything began working smoothly.

I was confused because other changes in CSS that I made *were* displayed. I might have known, because other browsers were displaying correctly, and Chrome has apparently supported linear-gradient without the -webkit- prefix for about a decade (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient#browser_compatibility).

Anyway, thank you to everyone who saw this and/or responded.

Answer (score -1):

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green, blue);
```

`-webkit-` is the css prefix for Chrome and Safari. I hope this will solve the problem.